# How to resize child images proportionally to parent?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a big image, in other words, a map. I also have markers which are attached to certain positions of the map. In the following, you can see an example.

[image]

The map and the markers are wrapped in `map-wraper` and are positioned absolute.

**HTML**

```
<div class="map-wrapper">
  <img src="map.png" id="map" alt="Map">
  <img src="marker-1.png" id="marker-1" alt="Shop">
  <img src="marker-2.png" id="marker-2" alt="House">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.map-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#marker-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 300px;
}

#marker-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

The problem is when I resize the browser, the markers get out of position. I want the markers also to be resized proportionally to their parents. In this case `map-wrapper`.

I have tried this CSS trick, but it didn't help. https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/

The reason why I don't just merge the markers with the map is that I want to give the markers hover effects.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Keep markers position on the map**

Use relative percentage units for markers' `top`and `left` CSS properties.

This way the markers should stay at the same position relative to their relatively positioned parent container `<div class="map-wrapper">`.

```
#marker-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: ...%;
  left: ...%;
}

#marker-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: ...%;
  left: ...%;
}
```

**Keep markers size relative to wrappers dimensions**

Use relative percentage units for markers' `height` and set their `width` to `auto`.

This way the markers should keep the same size relative to their relatively positioned parent container's `<div class="map-wrapper">` height.

```
#marker-1 {
 ... some properties here...
 height: ...%;
 width: auto;
}

#marker-2 {
 ... some properties here...
 height: ...%;
 width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That helps, but the markers are not being smaller proportionally to the map.

Comment: Define the marker size with - *width: ...%;* - to get smaller markers on resize.

Comment: Thank you! It works as I expected.

Answer (score -1):

Use calc() function instead to compute the position based on the browser size (%).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you provide me an example if you don't mind?

Comment: For example, if your marker is located 25% from the top and 10% from the left AND your marker is 50px by 50px, your code would probably like this: ```top: calc(25% - 25px); left: calc(10% - 25px);``` The subraction is for the marker to be centered at the point you wanted.

Comment: That's what I also tried at the beginning, but the markers are not being smaller proportionally to the map.